# How do I place a TextInput between two Text components and have it wrap nicely?

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I'm currently trying to place a TextInput between two Text components but it's not wrapping very nicely. This is what it looks like now where the text gets wrapped above the TextInput instead of being on the same line:

[image]

I would like to achieve something like the picture below here, where the Text wraps onto the same line as the TextInput:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.row_container}>  
        
        <Text>I have not been given notice of unpaid leave for a period of</Text>
        
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 30}}>
          <TextInput style={styles.text_input}/>
        </View>
        
        <Text>days on the date of this application. </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',    
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  row_container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  text_input: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderColor: 'grey',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
});
```

[Here's the snack link if it helps](https://snack.expo.dev/zOdy5Th0gV)

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the `TextInput` inside the `Text` like so:

```
<Text>
  {'I have not been given notice of unpaid leave for a period of '}
  <View style={{ width: 50, height: 10 }}>
    <TextInput style={styles.text_input} />
  </View>
  {' days on the date of this application.'}
</Text>
```

*The text inside `{''}` is to add extra space before and after the text input.*
*Also changed the View's height to avoid it taking extra space if the following text wraps below.*

[image: spacing]

**Edit:**
If you want to change height of TextInput you might need a bit hackish solution since `display: 'inline'` isn't supported in react native (only on web), look at the following where I add `lineHeight: 25` on `Text` and `marginBottom: -10` in `TextInput`:

```
  <Text style={{lineHeight: 25}}>
  {'I have not been given notice of unpaid leave for a period of '}
  <View>
    <TextInput style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', height: 30, width:50, marginBottom: -10 }} />
  </View>
  {' days on the date of this application. Lorem ipsum dotem done fou'}
</Text>
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I did not know you could put a View inside a Text! Thank you.     

But, is it not possible use a larger height? 

It seems that when I increase the height, the alignment of the [text does not stay centre-aligned.](https://imgur.com/rmvV8z3)

Comment: For that you have to add the style **in** the textInput, see the edit.

Comment: @WilsonChew Hi, tell me if the edit worked for you, I've thought of other cases but at that point it might come down to design choices & playing around with the solution provided.

Comment: Yes, it worked for me, just had to adjust lineHeight a little

Answer (score 0):

Seems css structure is not ok...

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.row_container}>  
        
        <Text>I have not been given notice of unpaid leave for a period of</Text>
        
        <View style={{display:"inline"}}>
          <TextInput style={styles.text_input}/>
        </View>
        
        <Text>days on the date of this application</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  row_container: {
   display:"inline"
  },
  text_input: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
     width: 50,
     height: 30,
     marginLeft:"10px",
       marginRight:"10px"
  },
});
```

https://snack.expo.dev/mh8RoCqYQ